# How can i create an ios configuration profile that will enable a device to sleep on a schedule?

Tags: ios, mdm

I'm trying to find a configuraton profile key that will change when a device will go to sleep.
I've looked at the [configuration reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW13) and I've found the Passcode policy lets you set a maxInActivity key to a number.

One option to enable the device to sleep (wake would be manual) would be periodically apply and un-apply this policy (OTA I guess) with a low number . But it seems really hacky.

Apple Configurator seems to have gimped the settings even more (the option for Passcode profile maxInactivity is just 1-5 minutes in the configurator.

I had 2 questions:

1. Has anyone else been able to create a policy that enables a device to sleep on a schedule?
2. Is it possible to access the configuration profile created by Apple Configurator (would save me hacking XML)

**UPDATE:** Answer to Q2 is fairly straightforward, if i export an unsigned profile from the configurator its open to read. Also found [this](http://help.apple.com/configurator/mac/1.4.1/) reference for Apple Configurator helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I think you are looking for a device lock operation. For this there is no way to do it periodically from the API. Use a cron job or any other scheduling mechanism based on your platform to push the device lock operation periodically. Also please note that if your device is already in sleep mode it wont call the device idle state. In that case this will be delayed and may polled in your server queue.